# Is it possible to execute the OnClick javascript function via selenium webdriver without the click

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am building a new test case and have ran into a new issue I am not sure how to get around. I need to click on an element that is both `visiblity: hidden` and `display: none` or at least need a way to execute the javascript function it calls. In the passed I have been able to use `IJavascriptExecutor` to change an elements visibility or display but this option is no good for this test case as I am dealing with an array of elements that I locate at runtime using `Driver.FindElements' so I cannot get the exact selector to use my old method for changing display.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
var script = String.Format("document.querySelector('{0}').style.display='inline-block';", selector);
js.ExecuteScript(script);
```

Attached is a screenshot of the html and the css attributes for the element in question.

The way I see it I have two options I can make this test not dynamic and exercise the functionality on a single hardcoded element (yuck!), or I can figure out how to do this dynamically. So my hope (probably a fools hope) is that I can somehow call the onClick event bound to this button without actually clicking on it. [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could extract the `onclick` attribute and send it as parameter. You also don't need to use `IJavaScriptExecutor`, `IWebDriver` extends this interface so you can just call [ExecuteJavaScript](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_Extensions_WebDriverExtensions_ExecuteJavaScript.htm) method

```
IWebElement buttonToClick;
string script = buttonToClick.GetAttribute("onclick");
driver.ExecuteJavaScript<object>(script);
```

You can also try clicking it with JavaScript

```
driver.ExecuteJavaScript<object>("arguments[0].click();", buttonToClick);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to execute a JavaScript click on a `IWebElement` via an `IJavaScriptExecutor`, regardless of visibility.

Sounds like your issue stems from not being able to identify which element to click at runtime, I would take a look at [XPaths](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

---

In the meantime, here's an example of how to JavaScript click all `<button>` elements with an `onclick` event attribute, using an XPath:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> buttons =
    Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//button[@onclick]"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
foreach (IWebElement button in buttons)
{
    js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
}
```